# HTML CSS div inside div with auto margin are off-center?

Tags: html, css, padding, center, margin

I have a divider that is centered in the page using `margin:auto`. Inside I have two more dividers (can't be combined, must be a divider nested in a divider) when I try to center something inside of this it does not center it in the center of the page. I'm assuming it has to do with the `padding-left` and `padding-right` that I've added...
Any insight?

Here's my code:

```
<center>
    <div style="margin:auto; width:80%;">
        <div style="width:50%; padding-left:20%; padding-right:20%;">
            <div style="width:inherit; position:absolute; bottom:0%;">
                <hr />
                test
                <hr />
                <br><br><br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</center>
```

Comment: I'm a little confused why you *have* to nest your DIVs. I can create your test DIV successfully (centered and everything) without nesting. As a footer, couldn't it exist outside the nesting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove the `center` tag:

```
<div style="margin:auto; width:80%;">
    <div style="width:50%; padding-left:20%; padding-right:20%;">
        <div style="width:inherit; position:absolute; bottom:0%;">
            <hr />
            test
            <hr />
            <br><br><br>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/V8qMm/

Comment: +1.  Also need to add `text-align:center;` in there somewhere.

Comment: @Jason Gennaro - Only if he wants the text to be centered.

Comment: Agreed @Joseph.  I think that is the intention.

Comment: Thank-you very much! Can anyone offer insight as to why the center tag would mess this up? Was is centering the padding?